# How to center text in a div element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create square element, that will have text centered both vertically and horizontally. Additionally, the whole area of the square should be a link. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="w1h1 medium">
    <a class="userLink" target="_blank" href="Fancybox.aspx">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
            <tr style="vertical-align: central">
                <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                    text in the middle 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </a>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
div.w1h1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.medium {
    background-color: #06849b;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

a.userLink
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: table;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer. In IE the text is at the top of the square, not in the middle. Can you help me with this?

I just created playground here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tschareck/yfnnm/

Comment: change `<tr style="vertical-align: central">` to `<tr style="vertical-align: middle">` http://jsfiddle.net/yWLYV/

Comment: Already tried that. That didn't change text position.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could simplify your structure a bit, and use `display:table-cell` on the `a` element.

**html**

```
<div class="w1h1 medium">
    <a class="userLink" target="_blank" href="Fancybox.aspx">
       text in the middle 
    </a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div.w1h1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background-color: #06849b;
}
a.userLink {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/yWLYV/1/

*works down to IE8*

Answer (score 11):

A great way to get perfectly centered text is to use a flexbox layout. You can horizontally and vertically center the content of a container element with very little code:

```
.container-with-centered-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/913fch6v/

Answer (score 1):

Change `<tr style="vertical-align: central">` to `<tr style="vertical-align: middle">` and `a.userLink` property `display` to `inline-block` or `inline`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWLYV/)

Comment: That's it! `display` CSS

Answer (score 1):

try my technique; follow this

```
.outer{ float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ccc; }
.innet{ float:left; width:100%; line-height:100px; text-align:center; }

<div class="outer">
        <span class="inner">This is my text</span>
</div>
```

and morpheus all right! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `line-height: 150px` to set the height of the content within the box. This should work well if there is only a single line of content.

Answer (score 1):

Use `valign="middle"` in the `<td>`

Example:

```
<td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" valign="middle">
   text in the middle 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Text here</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #06849b;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/8LwN9/).

Please note that it only allows one line of text... is that a problem?

EDIT, found a better solution, display the anchor as a table cell, works multiple line too:

```
a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #06849b;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/8LwN9/1/)